# SQlite3 and database creation

Tags: sqlite

why does this statement `rc= sqlite3_open("file.db",&db)` where rc is the integer variable always return zero ???.  this is the code

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <sqlite3.h> 

    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
     {
       sqlite3 *db;
       char *zErrMsg = 0;
       int rc;

       rc = sqlite3_open("test.db", &db);

       if( rc ){
       fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
       return(0);
     }
        else
      {
       fprintf(stderr, "Opened database successfully\n");
     }
       sqlite3_close(db);
    }
```

isn't it supposed to return 1(true) in case of succesful database creation ???

Comment: 0 means OK: https://www.sqlite.org/rescode.html#ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return value is not a boolean; you never must compare against `0` or `1`.

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html) says:

> If the database is opened (and/or created) successfully, then [SQLITE_OK](http://www.sqlite.org/rescode.html#ok) is returned. Otherwise an [error code](http://www.sqlite.org/rescode.html) is returned.